# How to create textbox with pull-down ? When enter something like a search text box , the matched data will be displayed in a pull-down

Tags: extjs, textbox

I want to display like the following image.[textbox with pulldown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15RVj.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's called [combobox](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html) field with remote query.

You can see example at [remote-combo example](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#remote-combo).

There is example with templating (headers like): [remote-loaded-combo](https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#remote-loaded-combo).